# angular animation after an http request completly load

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have problem with animation on data that comes from an api, for example if i want to achieve an angular 4 stagger animation i need to provide objects.lenght

```
<div [@listAnimation]="objects.length">
  <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
        {{ object?.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

and the problem is the value of objects.lenght is undifined for about less than a second or maybe more until my http request to api completes!

here is my component

```
 objects: {};

  constructor(private _api: ApiService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._api.getAllBlogPosts()
      .subscribe(result => this.objects= result);
  }
```

and the stagger animation is look like this

```
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style , query , stagger , keyframes} from '@angular/animations';
 
export const listAnimation =  

    trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [

            query(':enter' , style({ opacity: 0 }) , {optional: true}),

            query(':enter' , stagger( '300ms' , [
                animate('1s ease-in' , keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 0 , transform: 'translateY(-75px)' , offset: 0}),
                    style({opacity: .5 , transform: 'translateY(35px)' , offset: 0.3}),
                    style({opacity: 1 , transform: 'translateY(0)' , offset: 1})                  
                ]))
            ]) , {optional: true}),

            query(':leave' , stagger( '300ms' , [
                animate('1s ease-in' , keyframes([
                    style({opacity: 1 , transform: 'translateY(0)' , offset: 0}),
                    style({opacity: .5 , transform: 'translateY(35px)' , offset: 0.3}),
                    style({opacity: 0 , transform: 'translateY(-75px)' , offset: 1})                  
                ]))
            ]) , {optional: true})

        ]),
    ]);
```

is there any way to call or run the animation after the call is complete?

Comment: I don't know Angular 4, but in 1.x, I would wrap that in a `<div>` or `<span>`  and `ng-show` or `ng-if` based on `objects` being non-null

Comment: @Mawg thanks man, it solved my problem

Comment: Then I will copy the comment to an answer, and you can accept it, to help others in future. Welcome aboard & glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

You could use the lifecycle hooks of Angular, so that **OnInit**, you call the method of your service. At that moment you get the information needed. Then you run the animation implementing **AfterViewInit**.

Check https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
and https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

**Update 1**:

It is possible to implements multiple lifecycle hooks for a component.
Let's say your animation has two states (example from https://angular.io/guide/animations), it would look like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

    @Component({
    ...
    animations: [
      trigger('listAnimation', [
        state('inactive', style({
          backgroundColor: '#eee',
          transform: 'scale(1)'
        })),
        state('active',   style({
          backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
          transform: 'scale(1.1)'
        })),
        transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
        transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
      ])
    ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { 
  ...
  animationState = 'inactive';

  constructor(private _api: ApiService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._api.getAllBlogPosts()
      .subscribe(result => this.objects= result);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // run animation by changing the state
    this.animationState = this.animationState === 'inactive ' ? 'active' : 'inactive ';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i do not get it. is it possible to component implements 2 life cycle hooks? afterViewInit and OnInit both together,  and by the way i would be thankful if you could be more specific about running the animation implementing AfterVirewInit. how could i stop stagger animation from executing because it runs quickly and throught error before data being loaded

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. but based on solution above i should put animationState into [@listAnimation]="animationState " and then as i mentiond at first question i have an stagger animation witch needs objects.length. Is it possible to write something like this into component html ?  [@listAnimation]="{skills.length , animationState }"

Comment: Hello, it should be possible in your html to have something that looks like this :
<div [@animation]="{value: expVal, /* option1: value, option2: value */ }">...</div>
https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular 4, but in 1.x, I would wrap that in a `<div>` or `<span>` and `ng-show` or `ng-if` based on `objects` being non-null